# How to disable next/prev buttons animation in a p:wizard?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have PrimeFaces wizard with some panels, and next/prev buttons is drawn by wizard widget itself... But there is one problem - when i press next button before the last step, it hides with animation... Is it possible to disable this animation and hide next button instantly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you simply want to remove the fading effects on the wizard next button ?

These effects are done with Primefaces Javascript built-in functions, like:

```
PrimeFaces.widget.Wizard.prototype.showNextNav = function() {
    jQuery(this.nextNav).fadeIn();
}
PrimeFaces.widget.Wizard.prototype.hideNextNav = function() {
    jQuery(this.nextNav).fadeOut();
}
```

However, Primefaces creators have let the possibility of overriding them quite easily.
Just add this in your .xhtml page:

```
 <script>
 PrimeFaces.widget.Wizard.prototype.hideNextNav = function() {
        jQuery(this.nextNav).hide();
    }
 PrimeFaces.widget.Wizard.prototype.showNextNav = function() {
        jQuery(this.nextNav).show();
    }
 </script>
```

Tested and working on PF 5.1.